# Comparing every element in an array to each other at random

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I'm trying to compare every element in an array with each other and outputting the results. This in itself is simple enough using nested for loops.

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

for(let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
   for(let k = i + 1; k < a.length; k++) {
      console.log(a[i] + ' -> ' + a[k]);
   }
 }
```

For this the output would be

```
1 -> 2
1 -> 3
1 -> 4
1 -> 5
2 -> 3
2 -> 4
2 -> 5
3 -> 4
3 -> 5
4 -> 5
```

But I would like these to be random, so for example something like

1 -> 2

2 -> 5

3 -> 4

and so on

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Generate all pairs of comparison -> put them in an array -> shuffle the array.

Comment: Do you care if both random elements are the same, or must they be different?

Comment: @CertainPerformance Different would be preferable. Although the array I'm going to use will be all unique elements anyways.

Comment: the normal way you wrote, sometimes help other peoples who didn't need the random one.. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a function that selects a random element, slices out that element, and then selects another random element:

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const randomElementsFromArr = () => {
  const randIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
  const oneElement = arr[randIndex];
  const slicedArr = [...arr.slice(0, randIndex), ...arr.slice(randIndex + 1)];
  const anotherElement = slicedArr[Math.floor(Math.random() * slicedArr.length)];
  return [oneElement, anotherElement];
};
console.log(randomElementsFromArr().join(' -> '));
```

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

check this :

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var output = new Array();

for(let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
   for(let k = i + 1; k < a.length; k++) {
      output.push(a[i] + ' -> ' + a[k]);
   }
 }

for(let b = 0; b < output.length; b++) {
   console.log(Math.floor(Math.random() * output.length));
}
```